# Create sub-domain for multisite and multi languages?

Tags: multisite, multi-language

I have developed multisite in WordPress. I have created two multisite one for Hindi and another for English.

Hindi URL is: `http://example.com/hindi` and 
English URL is: `http://example.com`

Now my requirement is the URL for Hindi should like `http://hindi.example.com` and for English, it should be a default URL like `http://example.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to setup a multisite network, using subdomains and using subdirectories. Your current setup is for subdirectories and to change the URLs the way you want them you‘ll need to change the setup to use subdomains. This is a great article explaining the difference between those two setups and how to change from subdirectories to subdomains: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/change-multisite-sub-directories-sub-domains/

**Beware** that to setup WordPress multisite to use subdomains you’ll need to use wildcard subdomains. Make sure your hosting provider can set that up for you.